# Browser upload direct to s3, barebones Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Found a writeup on Heroku on uploading to private s3 buckets, direct from browsers:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node

For me, the aws-sdk package got in the way more than it helped.  The dubious s3upload script was another concern.

How does one upload directly to s3 without all the cruft in the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to dig up an old Java-based project to figure this one out.  Turns out it's nice and simple once you get down to the essentials.  First, setup a quick HTML form to do the upload:

```
<form action="https://BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com/"
      method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="key" value="KEY"></input>
  <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="ACCESS_KEY"></input>
  <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="POLICY"></input>
  <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="SIGNATURE"></input>
  <input type='file' name='file'>
  <input type='submit' value='Upload Driver Photo'>
</form>
```

Next, cook up a quick Node.JS script to generate values for `POLICY` and `SIGNATURE` above, the `encodedPolicy` and `signature` variables below.  Remember, both values must be base64 encoded:

```
var crypto=require("crypto"),
  bucketName="BUCKETNAME",
  secretKey="SECRET_KEY",
  s3Key="KEY",
  expiration= new Date();
expiration.setDate(expiration.getDate()+1);
var policy={
  expiration:expiration.toISOString(),
  conditions:[
    {bucket:bucketName},
    {key:s3Key}
  ]
},
  encodedPolicy=new Buffer(JSON.stringify(policy)).toString("base64"),
  signature=crypto.createHmac(
    "sha1", secretKey
  ).update(encodedPolicy).digest("base64");
```

Wrap the Node.JS code above in a Promise for extra tastiness.  Embed in Angular/REST, Express with templating, or other middleware/presentation framework of choice.

Please note: the code above does not limit the upload file size.  This would be done with another condition, i.e. for a 50MB limit: `["content-length-range", 0, 52428800]`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using [minio-js](https://github.com/minio/minio-js) as shown in the [example](https://github.com/minio/minio-js/blob/master/examples/presigned-putobject.js)

On the server get a presigned url for PUT like this:

```
var presignedUrl = s3Client.presignedPutObject('my-bucketname', 'my-objectname', 1000, function(e, presignedUrl) {
  if (e) return console.log(e)
  console.log(presignedUrl)
})
```

On the browser use this `presignedUrl` to make a simple PUT request to S3 to upload an object.